My plugin fails to compile for IOS on Github Action, but I can't see why
I'm trying to develop a React-Native plugin for using Stockfish 17. As for now I've managed to test it on an Android device. As I've generated the project recently (less than 3 days ago), it should match the latest React Native specifications.
But as I don't own a Mac computer, nor an Iphone, I'm just checking the Github Action workflow of my project ReactNativeStockfish in order to know if it has a chance to run on Ios. But in my last attempts, the build fails but there's no trace of any error in the logs (just some warnings) : I bet it's either because of a build timeout, or because the log was too long to be displayed completely.
So how can know what's going on really ?
Also, in order to generate the IOS code, as I've no expertise, I simply asked ChatGPT to adapt my Kotlin code, and try to correct the result as far as I could.

Back to the logs, I've seen that there were missing some *.nnue files, making the compilation failing. I'm trying to solve this issue.
